# $ajax done function is not working in ASP.NET -MVC5 application

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

I am using $ajax jquery function on partial razor view to get another partial view along with strongly typed model data from controller to page--> display in specific div. Now if data model data is there it works but in case if there is no model data, I am passing json response so that I can check on razor view in order to avoid null exception. My issue is done method in $ajax is not calling plus json response, I don't know where I am doing wrong

### Ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*Address*/
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DisplayStudentAddress")',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        alert(data.Response);

       $('#studentAddressDisplay').html(data);

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert(jqXHR +"    "+textStatus+"    "+errorThrown);
    });
});
```

### ActionResult Method

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult DisplayStudentAddress()
    {
        int _studentEntityID = 0;

        _studentEntityID = _studentProfileServices.GetStudentIDByIdentityUserID(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        Address _studentAddressModel = new Address();

        _studentAddressModel = _studentProfileServices.GetStudentAddressByStudentID(_studentEntityID);


        if (_studentAddressModel != null)
        {
            return PartialView("DisplayStudentAddress_Partial", _studentAddressModel);
        }
        else
        {
             return Json(new { Response = "Provide Your Address Detail!" });
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

I have check in debugging, json is called in controller but it alert error in ajax

Comment: `$('#studentAddressDisplay').html(result);` would need to be `$('#studentAddressDisplay').html(data);` (`response` does not exist) is that a typo?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: sorry my fault but is still the same case

Comment: not working.... error function is called

Comment: do I need to tell ajax to expect json???

Answer (score 3):

If your server returns empty string for a json response, jQuery treats it as failed. and empty string is considered invalid json.

As per official document [here](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string).

> As of 1.9, an empty string returned for JSON data is considered to be
>   malformed JSON (because it is); this will now throw an error.

try below code instead with using `.always`:-

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DisplayStudentAddress")',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false
    }).always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    alert(data.Response);

   $('#studentAddressDisplay').html(data);

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert(jqXHR +"    "+textStatus+"    "+errorThrown);
    });
```

Because .`done` is executed only if everything works successfully so if there will be something wrong `.done` will not be called. But the `always` method will always get triggered regardless your ajax request works or not.

Comment: Does it? Can you provide some proof of this? (I'm not saying I don't believe you by the way - but returning null is valid)

Comment: As of 1.9, an empty string returned for JSON data is considered to be malformed JSON (because it is); this will now throw an error. http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string @jumpingcode

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't know that. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is in controller action method, modify as following;

```
 return Json(new { Response = "Provide Your Address Detail!", RecordStatus ="Not Available" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code for this:

```
 if (data.itemCount == 0) {
                        $('#row-' + data.deleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    } else {
                        $('#item-count-' + data.deleteId).text(data.itemCount);
                    }

                    $('#cart-total').text(data.cartTotal);
                    $('#update-message').text(data.message);
                    $('#cart-status').text(data.cartCount);
```